# gitlab integration youtrack add comments of commits

Tags: youtrack, gitlab-ce

I'm setting up the integration of `gitlab` with `youtrack`,
I can't port comments in commits, can you tell me how to do it?

[image]

I want them to be here...

[image]

however, everything comes to the mail correctly.

[image]

Comment: this type of commetns are not synced